# What is the difference between Sentiment Analysis and Emotion Recognition?

Tags: definitions, comparison, emotional-intelligence, sentiment-analysis

I found Sentiment Analysis and Emotion Recognition as two different categories on [paperswithcode.com](https://paperswithcode.com/). Should both be the same as my understanding? If not what's the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sentiment in this context refers to evaluations, typically positive/negative/neutral. [Sentiment Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentiment_analysis) can be applied to product reviews, to identify if the reviewer liked the product or not. This has (in principle) got nothing to do with emotions as such.

[Emotion recognition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emotion_recognition) would typically work on conversational data (eg from  conversations with chatbots), and it would attempt to recognise the emotional state of the user -- angry/happy/sad...

Of course the same can overlap: if the user is happy, they will typically express positive sentiments on something.

Also: emotion recognition goes beyond text (eg facial expressions), whereas sentiment analysis mostly works with textual data only.

Answer (score 0):

**Sentiment Analysis** -- the most common text classification that analyses an incoming message and tells whether the underlying sentiment is positive, negative, or neutral.

**Emotion Recognition**-- emotion recognition refers to the cognitive and behavioral strategies people use to influence their own emotional experience.

Note: This explanation is based on the paper that I have read.